# Check whether user is currently online (live)

Tags: php, jquery

I've recently finished my application and I've got a huge problem. I need to allow only 1 user to access it at a time. There is an index page accessible for every user everytime and "start" button. When user clicks start, the application locks and other ppl need to wait until the user finishes. When the user closes tab/browser, the application has to unlock automatically. Each user has 5 minutes to use my app. 
I partially solved my problem, but it still doesn't work properly - on every site I set the jquery script that every 5 seconds triggers "extend.php" file on the server ($.get() function). The php file modifies time.txt file (it changs it to time()+5) and the script on the intex site checks whether (time()>time.txt content). So that when the uses closes tab/browser, the app is accessible. Obviously my app is also based on sessions (when the user closes browser, he loses access). 
On some computers it simply doesn't work (it seems jquery doesnt trigger extend.php file and it makes my app accessible all the time). 
So my question is: do you see any other ways to solve my problem?

The descr might be messy but I wanted to describe everything strightforward ;)

Regards.

Comment: What OS/browser is it not working on.   Start from there and see if there is some commonality among those having the problem.  You may be chasing a code issue that is really a browser issue.

Comment: You're doing the right thing in principle by the sound of it.  First thing to do is to get on a machine on which it doesn't work, and see if it's throwing any visible browser errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an a jQuery unload function so that when they click the close button your web browser executes one last line of script before the user exits. Example:

```
$(window).unload(function(){

   "your php function to unlock the app here"

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is OK, it should work. Yes, node.js, or any other server side javascript can be used to do the same, but having a script triggered is by far the easiest solution. You really should focus your time to investigate further on what machines it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If it is restrained to 5 minutes, then set it to expire in 5 minutes. You can use a counter in  jquery to show how much time is available. When it hits the expiration then notify the user time is up. Once time has expired or the user is finished with the app update the time.txt to time() or however you normally handle it when the app is accessible. No polling and 1 update.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `LOCK` on a mysql table when a user is online and unlock it when they are offline.

The only issue is if your code forgets to unlock.